# How to retry DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch items?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want retry failed items when dynamodbmapper.save/writeitem return some unprocessedItems.
Below are my code snippet which I have tried so far.

```
    List<UserDetails> userDetails = buildUserDeatails();
    //List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> failedBatches = mapper.batchSave(userDetails);
    List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> failedBatches = mapper.batchWrite(userDetails,new ArrayList<UserDetails>());
    System.out.println("Failed batches" + failedBatches.size());
    for (FailedBatch failedBatch : failedBatches) {
        System.out.println("Failed batches process start*********");
        Map<String, List<WriteRequest>> batchUnprocessedItems = failedBatch.getUnprocessedItems();
        System.out.println("Failed batches process size from mapper*********" + batchUnprocessedItems.size());
        do {
            if (batchUnprocessedItems.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("All items processed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Gathering unprocessed items...and retrying using batchWrite");
                BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItemUnprocessed(batchUnprocessedItems);
                System.out.println("After Retry...and retrying using batchWrite "
                        + outcome.getUnprocessedItems().size());
                batchUnprocessedItems = outcome.getUnprocessedItems();
                System.out.println("Rerty done***********");
            }
        } while (batchUnprocessedItems.size() > 0);
    }
    System.out.println("end process");
}
```

***To test above piece of code, I have mapped wrong table name in userPojo class(Which is not exists in dynamoDB)***

When retry logic is executing it is throwing
  ***com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: xxxxxxxx)"***

As per the documentation, If something failed it should be return in **BatchWriteItemOutcome** object but in my case it is throwing error.

I am using below Maven dependency

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.748</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB class uses AmazonDynamoDB client under the hood. You can check it reading the sources from aws-java-sdk-dynamodb. Now, if we look in the documentation of the AmazonDynamoDB#batchWriteItem method we see this:

> ResourceNotFoundException - The operation tried to access a nonexistent table or index. The resource might not be specified correctly, or its status might not be ACTIVE

So the exception is somehow expected here.

Also, looking at your code I noticed you retry to process the unprocessed items over and over again without a timeout. It is suggested to use a back-off strategy when you retry unprocessed operations with DynamoDB.

[AmazonDynamoDB#batchWriteItem documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchWriteItemRequest-)